# GCP Storage - unable to add new files / folders, but no errors provided

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, upload, google-cloud-storage, storage

In the past few days, I created my first GCP project and hosted my Angular app in a Storage bucket. (The app.yaml and dist folder.) This worked great, got everything running and pointed a domain at it. I rolled out one update to the dist folder a day or two ago.

Today I did some updates to the app and generated a new dist hoping to update the app, but now I am finding I cannot update any content in the bucket at all. If I click "upload folder / file" or drag in content to upload, it shows a loading snackbar for a split second, then immediately says "0 files uploaded successfully". No error is given, but nothing is uploaded.

If I click "create folder" it gives me the error message

> "Unable to create your folder. Try again or contact your
> administrator."

But I am the owner / creator of the project, the bucket, etc.

Things I have tried:

- Double checked permissions and given myself specific permission for the bucket
- Confirming I can make content in other buckets (I can)
- Uploading content into sub-folders of the dist (Same errors as before)

I'm trying to find a way to get more definitive error logs from this, but the feedback I'm getting from the UI is very vague at the moment. I'm new to GCP, so I'm not sure where to look to get something more informative.

Comment: I suggest you close your browser, clear the cache and try again. Otherwise, if you have the `gcloud` SDK installed? We can try to use the command line.

Comment: I second the previous comment ... but after installing the GCP SDK, look/study using the gsutil command.  This is the CLI interface to GCS.  You should always prefer scripted or automated tasks over manual UI based ones (whereever possible).

Comment: Use the Chrome debugger and double-check the error reported in the debugger. My guess: a JS library is not being downloaded due to a transient error.

Comment: I've now tried uploading files or creating folders from an entirely different computer and I get the exact same errors. The errors are mostly 404s for things like PAGE_STATE, GCS_OBJECT, LOGS_VIEWER, SIDENAV_COMPACT, heartbeat, and pagead/viewthroughconversion. As far as I cantell, these are the same errors that occur on other buckets that work.

I have gcloud installed, I'm going to try the gsutil commands next and see if that works for me.

Comment: SOLIVED: I created a new file and used gsutil cp testfile gs://my-bucket-name/ and got the following error:

AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a delinquent billing account.

Why this error didn't appear ANWHERE else is bizarre. Updated it to the new billing account I made a few days ago and everything is functioning again. Why it was working before  and suddenly broke due to the billing account it had from the start is also bizarre.

I guess the lesson from this is use gsutil, because their UI swallows the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The GCP UI swallows all errors. It would fail without presenting any reason why. Use gsutil commands to actually surface the errors. In my case I ran this command:

```
gsutil cp testfilename gs://my-bucket-name
```

That threw the following error:

> AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a delinquent billing account.

The project existed on a generic billing account named "My Billing Account" that was auto generated. I had created a new billing account a day prior to the bug in order to run `gcloud app deploy` on the API project (separate gcloud project from the project hosting the broken bucket). After this billing account was made, it made the generic billing account defunct, but it did not alert me to this in any part of the UI. Only the gsutil command exposed the error. No debug tool errors, no UI errors. The generic "My Billing Account" that they created doesn't even appear in the possible list of billing accounts to select from.

So lesson learned: don't trust the GCP UI. Use command line tools to expose errors.